# I lose my Explore on ubuntu 20.04 , please help

Tags: 22.04, filesystem, directory

I was trying to connect my Samsung S21 to my ubuntu and perform some instructions:

```
root@spike:~# history | grep mt
    1  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
    4  sudo apt-get install mtpfs
    6  sudo apt-get install gmtp
    7  sudo apt-get remove gmtp
    8  sudo apt-get install mtpfs
    9  sudo apt-get install gmtp
   23  history | grep mtp
```

After this m Explore icon desappear and I am not able to browse my Folder.
I try to re-install ubuntu 22.04 but I get some errors and Explorer don't appear.

Please Help, i don't want to lose my data.

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again ? means `reboot`

Comment: Yes, i reboot the PC but still I don't see the icon to brouwse my filesystem. I can browse using a terminal session.
Is there a command that will reinstall ubuntu 22.04 again?

Comment: The PPA you added doesn't contain anything useful to you, and hasn't been touched in a decade. You may be better off installing GSConnect or KDE Connect to get data from your phone to your desktop. MTP is awfully unreliable and slow.